# Fetch handling promise

Tags: reactjs, promise, fetch

Im using this setup for my app:

- ReactJS
- KarmaJS
- Instanbul

At this point i keep receiving this error:
`Object is not a constructor (evaluating '(0, _whatwgFetch2['default'])')`

While checking the web it keeps telling me to import whatwg-fetch which I actually already did so I am a bit lost where to go.

**My method that executes the call:**

```
import fetch from 'whatwg-fetch';

export function authenticateUser(username, password) {

  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({type: 'LOGIN'});

    return fetch(getState().config.components.Authentication.login_endpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
      })
    }).then(resp => {
      if (resp.status === 302) {
        window.location = resp.url;
      } else if (resp.status >= 300 && resp.status < 500) {
        return Promise.resolve(resp);
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(resp.statusText);
      }
    }).then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(resp => {
        const error = data.errors[0];
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_FAILED', payload: error.detail });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error); // I know, still needs to be catched 
    });
  };
}
```

**My testcase:**

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { authenticateUser } from '../../src/actions/index';

const initialConfig = {
  authentication: {
    loginform_loading: false,
    loginform_errorMessage: null,
    forgotpassword_loading: false,
    forgotpassword_errorMessage: null,
    forgotpassword_passwordSent: false
  },
  config: {
    components: {
      Authentication: {
        'login_endpoint': '/api/auth/login',
        'forgotpassword_enabled': true,
        'forgotpassword_path': '/auth/forgot-password',
        'forgotpassword_endpoint': '/auth/forgot-password'
      }
    }
  }
};

const middlewares = [ thunk ];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);
let store;

describe('Action/Index/authenticateUser', () => {

  const testUsername = 'User';
  const testPassword = 'Test123';
  let sandbox;

  beforeEach(function () {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
    store = mockStore(initialConfig);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('LOGIN is dispatched', () => {
    var response = mockResponse(400, 'Found', '{"errors": [{ "message": "first" }] }');
    sandbox.stub(window, 'fetch')
      .resolves(response);

    return store.dispatch(authenticateUser(testUsername, testPassword))
      .then(() => {
        var expectedActions = store.getActions();
        expect(expectedActions).to.not.be.empty;

        var action = expectedActions[0];
        expect(action.type).to.equal('LOGIN');
      });
  });
});
```

Hope that somebody can help me on what is wrong. And maybe also on how to improve the error handling in the Promise itself

Thanks,
Pim

Comment: Try to change your import line to just `import 'whatwg-fetch'`

Comment: This is it! Did something change on that one that it worked before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panther gave the correct answer on this one.

`import 'whatwg-fetch'` did the trick